# Static Friction and Centripetal Force for woman attached to spinning disc

Tags: forces, friction, centripetal-force

Lets say a woman is attached to the center of a spinning disc with a rope ,and she also has friction between her shoes and the surface of the disc.

A problem I am doing says that the force pointing to the center (the centripetal force) includes friction and tension.

Tension i understand that it pulls her inwards. But how can static friction provide part of that centripetal force?

Static Friction opposes relative motion. So how does it point inward? her velocity vector is tangential but always changing direction.

Comment: *Relative* motion.  The motion of her shoes *relative* to the disc.

Comment: hm, I may not be as familiar with relative motion as i thought. she is moving in a circle, thats the only motion there is isnt she? and relative to the disc she isnt moving at all.

Comment: Exactly.  Relative to the disk she is not moving at all.  Perhaps your confusion is between *static* friction (zero relative motion) and *kinetic* friction (non-zero relative motion).

Comment: hm, so relative to the disc she is not moving at all, but how does that dictate the direction of the static friction to point radially inward?  thanks for answering!

Comment: Remove the rope, and replace the woman with a box (low cg.) and see how friction contributes to centripetal force.

Comment: Think about which way she would have flown without friction. She would be flying outwards, out of the circle, right? Static friction holds her fixed by pulling inwards.

Answer (score 0):

Static friction prevents any movement up to a certain strength of the force. Thus you can consider the shoes of the lady being glued to the disk in this regime. As the lady follows the circular motion of the disk, she has a centripetal acceleration and thus force mediated over the shoes or string as long as shoe doesn't move relative to the disk. She herself feels a fictitiuos centrifugal  force relative to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Static friction opposes net force, not relative motion because there is no relative motion when static force dominates.

You can adopt the spinning frame (simple solution) or the ground frame.

In the spinning frame, there is a virtual outward centrifugal force hence the opposing inward static friction force.

In the ground frame, the disc is turning due to some mechanical apparatus. The disc is accelerating inwards. On top of the disk is an object ***resisting*** this acceleration (like a box on top of an accelerating box). So the friction force felt by ***the disc*** is outwards. By the third law, the friction force on ***the object*** is inwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing fall in the category of "statically indeterminate" problems when two or more unknown forces act along the same direction and their magnitudes cannot be established using the equations of motion, or the balance of forces only.

Here is a description of all the forces that might be acting on the person if both feet are in contact with the disk.

[image: fbd]

Where:

$$\begin{aligned}
  m g & : & &\mbox{Force of gravity (Weight)} \\
  T & : & &\mbox{Tension on rope} \\
  N_F & : & &\mbox{Front normal force } \\
  N_B & : & &\mbox{Back normal force } \\
  F_F & : & &\mbox{Front friction force } \\
  F_B & : & &\mbox{Back normal force } \\
  m \Omega^2 R & : & &\mbox{Centrifugal force} \\
  R & : & &\mbox{Orbit radius of the center of mass} \\
  a & : & &\mbox{Front foot location relative to cg} \\
  b & : & &\mbox{Back foot location relative to cg} \\
  c & : & &\mbox{Height of rope relative to cg} \\
  h & : & &\mbox{Height of cg relative to disk} \\
\end{aligned}$$

There are three balance equations (sum of forces and sum of moments), but 5 unknowns (the 2 normal forces, the 2 frictions forces, and the rope tension).

I can think of two possible scenarios to the above problem:

1. The disk is frictionless and $F_F=0$, $F_B=0$ with solution

   > $$ \begin{aligned} 
   >   T & = m \Omega^2 R \\
   >   N_F & = m \frac{b g + c\, \Omega^2 R}{a+b} \\
   >   N_B & = m \frac{a g - c\, \Omega^2 R}{a+b} \\
   > \end{aligned} $$
2. The back foot isn't in contact and $N_B=0$, $F_B=0$ with solution

   > $$ \begin{aligned} 
   >   T & = m \frac{\Omega^2 R h- ag}{h-c} \\
   >   N_F & = m g \\
   >   N_B & = m \frac{c\, \Omega^2 R-a g}{c-h} \\
   > \end{aligned} $$

The actual solution is going to be some combination of the above two solutions.

Now I think you are asking what happens if the rope tension is known (the person is *actively* pulling with $T$ force)? Then the two friction forces are going to add up to $F_F+F_B = m \Omega^2 R-T$, but we won't know how much goes where unless there are further assumptions made.